# derivative of integral

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-derivative

How can I proceed to find the symbolic derivative below:

$$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial v}\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\sqrt{\frac{v+1}{v+z^{2}}}}\left(1+\dfrac{t^{2}}{v+1}\right)^{-(\frac{v+2}{2})}dt$$

I have already tried on the Maple and in the R and I have not been able to, in addition, it is not possible to use the fundamental theorem of calculus. The nucleus of the integral is of Student's t-distribution with $(v+1)$ freedom degrees. Leibniz rule don't can be applied because one of the limits of integration is infinite!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How the nucleus of the integral is of Student's t-distribution, we can do

\begin{align}
\displaystyle \dfrac{\partial}{\partial v}\left( \int_{-\infty}^{\sqrt{\frac{v+1}{v+z^{2}}}}\left(1+\dfrac{t^{2}}{v+1}\right)^{-(\frac{v+2}{2})}dt\right)
&=\displaystyle \dfrac{\partial}{\partial v}\left( t \  _2F_1 \left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{v}{2}+1; \frac{3}{2};-\frac{t^2}{v+1}\right)|_{-\infty}^{\sqrt{\frac{v+1}{v+z^{2}}}}\right) \\
&=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial v}\displaystyle \sqrt{\frac{v+1}{v+z^{2}}} \  _2F_1 \left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{v}{2}+1; \frac{3}{2};-\frac{\left(\sqrt{\frac{v+1}{v+z^{2}}}\right)^2}{v+1}\right)-0\\
&=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial v}\displaystyle \sqrt{\frac{v+1}{v+z^{2}}} \ _2F_1 \left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{v}{2}+1; \frac{3}{2};-\frac{1}{v+z^{2}}\right)\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{\dfrac{v+z^2}{v+1}}\dfrac{z^2-1}{(v+z^2)^2}\times \ _2F_1 \left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{v}{2}+1; \frac{3}{2};-\frac{1}{v+z^{2}}\right)\\ 
&+ \sqrt{\frac{v+1}{v+z^{2}}} \times \dfrac{\partial}{\partial v}
 \left[\ _2F_1 \left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{v}{2}+1; \frac{3}{2};-\frac{1}{v+z^{2}}\right)\right]
\end{align}

and
\begin{align}
\displaystyle \dfrac{\partial}{\partial v}
 \left[\ _2F_1 \left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{v}{2}+1; \frac{3}{2};-\frac{1}{v+z^{2}}\right)\right]&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left[-\dfrac{(n+\frac{1}{2})}{(n+\frac{3}{2})(n+1)}\dfrac{z^2-2n-2}{2(v+z^2)^2}\right]
\end{align}

I still need to simplify this to implement in R!

Comment: You should edit your original post/post a new question for someone to assist you with simplifying this series.

Answer (score 1):

[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cleft(1%2B%5Cdfrac%7Bx%5E%7B2%7D%7D%7By%2B1%7D%5Cright)%5E%7B-(%5Cfrac%7By%2B2%7D%7B2%7D)%7D) gives
$$\int\left(1+\dfrac{t^{2}}{v+1}\right)^{-(\frac{v+2}{2})} \ dt = x \  _2F_1 \left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{v}{2}+1; \frac{3}{2};-\frac{t^2}{v+1}\right) + C$$

where $_2F_1(a,b;c;x)$ is the [hypergeometric function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunction.html), in particular,

$$_2F_1 \left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{v}{2}+1; \frac{3}{2};-\frac{t^2}{v+1}\right)= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left[ \frac{(n+\frac{1}{2})(n+(\frac{v}{2}+1))}{(n +\frac{3}{2})(n+1)} \left(-\frac{t^2}{v+1}  \right )  \right].$$

This is at least some progress towards the solution. But even at this point you've got some ungodly computation to deal with.

Comment: Replacement of $x$ for $t$ in the first equality. I could not edit!

Comment: @fsbmat Fixed that, sorry!